# Washed out primary screen colors Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: nvidia, gnome, ubuntu-gnome, display-manager

I recently dual booted my MSI GP63, and installed ubuntu 19.04, but my laptop screen looks little washed out even after installing nvidia drivers version: 418,

But when i connect to secondary display, on that display colours looks perfectly fine. can someone please help me out with this. I suspect this might have something related to gnome-desktop

I tried the command as suggested at multiple places as well as

`xrandr --output eDP-1 --set "Broadcast RGB" "Full"`

but this also did nothing. Can someone please suggest is there any other way to fix this issue or is this my life now ?

Comment: Have checked if there is any Colour profiling option for your laptop screen in Settings->Devices->Colour ?

Comment: yes i have checked, tried to change it, delete it nothing happens. after every change i even logged out and logged in. I even tried to copy the color profiles from windows of this laptop only still no change. even did same with mac

Comment: I think you might have a better chance for an answer by posting in the nvidia forum https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/board/98/ this link should take you to the linux section.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is  to enable Coolbits in the nvidia control panel to check if there is any settings for the screen colours.

To enable coolbits you need to have a configuration for your nvidia card either in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` or `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` or `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/`
If there is no file you could create a file called `10-nvidia.conf` with the following content
`    Section "Module"
        Load "modesetting"
    EndSection

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
    Option         "Coolbits" "28"
EndSection`
```

You could also try to install the latest drivers from the Graphics Drivers ppa here https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Comment: yes these both sections were missing from the file. I already have the latest drivers i.e. 418

Comment: but still not change

Comment: Latest driver is 430

Comment: Yes, i saw they were released just yesterday and in nvidia thread some people are having trouble using it, thats why i didnt installed that yet.